# Menschen vs Menschheit

Tags: grammar-identification

> Die Energieressourcen, aus denen die Mensch(heit) auf dieser Erde schöpfen kann, werden immer knapper.

In the above sentence, the bracketed part was  replaced with a blank, and the question was to fill the blank. I had to put "Menschen" but apparently the approriate the correct answer is "Menschheit". Could someone explain why that would be so?

Comment: [Refer](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/74826/exercise-in-usage-preference-of-singular-vs-kollektiv-singular)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use “Menschen”, however that is plural, so it would not be in agreement with “kann”.

Comment: How did you figure out that is the subject of the relative sentence?

Comment: @SBrian, how else would you analyse the sentence?

Comment: @S Brian: this isn't passive voice and *können* isn't one of the few verbs that can go without a subject in active voice. So you need a subject, and there isn't another item that could be the subject.

Comment: I was confused on how to chosse subject from the three "denen" "die Menschheit" "auf dieser Erde"

Comment: It's *aus denen*. There's a preposition in front so it can't be the subject. Same for *auf dieser Erde*.

Comment: Please add the last comment into your answer. It is very very important @Janka