# Can prepositional object be a subject?

Tags: grammar-identification

In the discussions in the comments of [this answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/74865/51342), this jaw dropping point was mentioned:

> It's aus denen. There's a preposition in front so it can't be the subject. Same for auf dieser Erde.

Is this always true? I have a hard time believing this as in English we can actually have prepositional object as subject [see here](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2018/06/prepositional-subject.html). And, since German is very similar to English in a first order approximation, it seems very weird.

Comment: Possibly the point of view of the German grammar is different. In your examples I recognize not a single subject which would survive translation to German (just the English SPO order requiring them to be), but adverbials of different flavours.

Comment: I'd argue in your linked examples the real subject is not the prepositional object, but always something else, but - breaking the usual SVO word order in English: "Over the mantle is a good place for the mirror” --> usual word order in English "A good place for the mirror would be over the mantle. So does the subject change just by rephrasing? I don't think so... It's "A good place" either way. It's similar to German putting different emphasis here, breaking usual word order deliberately. But that's a discussion on English grammar which is off-topic here.

Comment: You recognize the wierdness of your statement "can an object be a subject"?

Comment: I don't actually. I am not very good at grammar @tofro

Comment: *Nach den Wahlen ist vor den Wahlen.*

Comment: I don't understand. COuld you explain what you intend to mean? @DavidVogt

Comment: He means that a copula as *sein* may connect two arbitrary items. That sentence has no subject. They are both adverbials.

Comment: Even if a prepositional phrase may - in rate cases - be a subject, if it is a subject, it cannot be an *object*. A phrase cannot be subject and object at the same time.

Comment: Note the difference between a prepositional _object_ (the object of a preposition, in your example _denen_) and a prepositional _phrase_ (a preposition plus any objects it may have, in your case _aus denen_). Prepositional _objects_ can never be subjects, because they are embedded in a prepositional phrase, and subjects cannot be embedded (like verbs, they are top-level constituents of sentences). Prepositional _phrases_, however, can be top-level constituents and can function as subjects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is all about the English sentence

> From five to seven would be the best time.

from your second link, and its literal German equivalent

> Von fünf bis sieben wäre die beste Zeit.

which is indeed valid German. But I think the author of that article is confused about the English, and especially the word order in her own example. That's a copula phrase and that means both items right and left of the verb refer to the subject.

In that special corner case, English lifts its strict word order rule. The sentences

> The best place is there.

and

> There is the best place.

are equivalent apart from the very fact that the latter is topicalized. It's not obvious because English topicalized sentences usually start with the topic separated by a comma. But not with a copula. English follows the common Germanic habit in that case and exposes its long forgotten V2 nature.

So what is that *there*? It's an adverb. No one would argue it was a "prepositional subject" because there's no preposition. It's an adverbial. It tells the place. **It is not the subject.** The subject is of course *The best place.*

And it's the same for the original example sentence.

> The best time would be from five to seven.

> From five to seven would be the best time.

Again, those sentences are equivalent but for the topic. ***From five to seven* is not the subject.** It's an adverbial that is coupled to the subject *The best time.*

And it's the same in German.

There are no prepositional subjects.

---

I see, further down she cites *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* with the sentence

> Over a year was spent on this problem.

and indeed *over a year* is the subject in this sentence. The problem with her argument however is that this *over* isn't a preposition. But an adverb that describes *a year* in more detail. It's *more than a year*.

It's not a direction we are talking about, and neither does it mean *during* —that would both be the preposition *over*— and neither it's the prepositional object of the phrasal verb *to spend on* — that one is *on this problem*.

This is very different from her own initial example

> Over the mantle is a good place for the mirror.

where *over* is indeed a preposition as it describes a direction, and of course *over the mantle* isn't the subject in this case. But an adverbial that is connected to the subject *a good place for the mirror*.

Comment: What does "topicalized" mean?

Comment: The topic is "what we need to talk about". You can pick one thing from the sentence and make it the topic. For example, If you had an argument about when to meet and there were many different times discussed, you make the time the topic because that's "what we need to talk about".

Comment: Compare *We go to the Alps in winter.* and *In winter, we go to the Alps.* The latter sentence is topicalized.

Comment: In English, the topic is usually put in a little extra clause in front and it's not used very often. In German, the topic is used all the time — it's the item in front of the V2 verb.

Comment: What about *from nine to five is good*?

Comment: Those are two adverbials labeled as equivalent. There is no subject.

Comment: +1! I'm no grammar expert, but this reads quite sound and convincing to me. Thanks for this nice and elaborate answer and excursion also into English

Comment: I don't see why *from nine to five is good* and *your proposal is good* should be analysed differently. Aren't English clauses supposed to always have a subject?

Comment: I wonder if, or why this is even grammatical. Even in German I would put it as *Am Mittag ist **es** gut.* introducing a dummy subject.

Comment: In ‘over a year’, the word _over_ is quite unambiguously a preposition. It is not an adverb. The fact that the meaning of the whole phrase is the same as ‘more than a year’ does not change the word class of _over_. And if prepositional phrases cannot be subjects, how do you explain perfectly valid sentences like, “Next to my mother is behind my brother” where both subject and subject predicate are PPs? As @DavidVogt says, English sentences always have subjects. You cannot label two adverbials as equivalent without making one the subject. (Incidentally, _good_ is not adverbial, but adjectival.)

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet: *Over over a year, we worked on the problem.* That first *over* is a preposition. The second isn't.

Comment: That is not correct. They are both prepositions. The first has a prepositional phrase as its object, the second has a noun phrase as its object. Adverbs do not take objects.

Comment: No, but adverbs can modify nouns. Especially when the noun specifies an amount, a duration or similar. What is *more* in *more than* to you? Or, in general e.g. *much* in *much trouble* ?

Comment: No, adverbs do not modify nouns; adjectives and determinatives do. But adverbs can modify prepositional phrases (as in ‘far from it’ or ‘directly above him’). _Much_ and _more_ are adverbs when modifying verbs (‘do you write much?’), adjectives (‘more common’) and PPs (‘more than X’). Both (as well as _many_) can also be determinatives and head DPs (or pre-modify NPs if you don’t believe in DPs), as in ‘much trouble’, ‘many/more people’ (modifying _trouble_ and _people_), or even in one-word DPs like ‘much has been said about this’ (here with the DP/NP as subject).