# Can we refer to a noun in a prepositional object/ oblig adv complement in a relative clause?

Tags: grammar-identification, relative-clause

I believe the answer is no, but I can't explain why.  I feel there maybe some tangential relation to [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/74883/can-prepositional-object-be-a-subject).

Could someone help?

---

Example:

> Eine Möglichkeit des Umgangs mit einem solchen Aufschiebungsverhalten kann sein, d(ie) als störend oder unangenehm eingestufte Handlung in mehrere Teile aufzuspalten, um die Aufgabe weniger groß oder auch weniger bedrohlich erscheinen zu lassen.

I was asked to fill in the blank with the bracketted part removed. I intuitively ruled out Aufschiebungsverhalten as a possibility. After some introspection, I found the stated rule to be the basis.... but I am not sure if it is actually a correct or good justification.

[Related](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/75664/translating-sentences-with-multiple-prepositional-objects-oblig-adverbial-compl).

Comment: I think i maybe understands your question, but could you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, sure. E.g.

> Er wartet auf den Bus, den er schon kommen sehen kann.
>
> Der Bus fährt zum Bahnhof, der am anderen Ende des Ortes liegt.
>
> Von dort fährt der Zug in die Schweiz ab, die er immer schon mal bereisen wollte.

---

Your example is **not** related to your question, as the clause introduced by *die* isn't a relative clause but an infinitive clause. That *die … Handlung* is the accusative object of that clause.

> Eine andere Möglichkeit ist, das Bett aufzusuchen und sich auszuruhen.